# Matrix-Vector Multiplication Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code I have written so far, but I'm not getting my desired output. I want to know what's missing in the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def matVec(matrix,vector): 
  for i in range(len(matrix)): 
    result = [] 
    total = 0 
    for j in range(len(vector)): 
      total += matrix[i][j] * vector[j] 
  result.append(total) 
  return result 
matrix_0 = [[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]] 
vector_0 = [2, 2] 
print(matVec(matrix_0,vector_0))
```

[link to code](https://repl.it/repls/PunctualGiantYottabyte)

Comment: Sorry, my browser doesn't support pictures. How about copy pasting your code here as text? Wouldn't that be easier than taking pictures of it and uploading it to an image hosting service and pasting the link here?

Comment: def matVec(matrix,vector):
  for i in range(len(matrix)):
    result = []
    total = 0
    for j in range(len(vector)):
      total += matrix[i][j] * vector[j]
  result.append(total)
  return result
matrix_0 = [[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]]
vector_0 = [2, 2]
print(matVec(matrix_0,vector_0))

Comment: Thanks for pasting it in the comments where the formatting is totally lost...

Comment: sorry, I have attached a link to my code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of code are useless. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why you should avoid posting images. Code and errors are in text, and should be posted as such. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with this site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.

Comment: Try it now: https://repl.it/repls/UncomfortableFussyMention

Comment: it's giving me [6,10], I'm missing 14 the output [6,10,14].

Comment: When you say words like "I'm not getting my desired output" you should probably follow that up with what output you desire ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes the trick. The bug was in the way you declared the original matrix. In particular, you have to declare the matrix grouping the elements in the rows, not the one in the columns like in the starting code

You are going to multiply the elements on the rows of `matrix` for the elements of the [column] `vector` in order to respect the rule for a multiplication matrix vs vector. Given a matrix with size `a`[= rows size, 3 in your case] x `b`[= columns size, 2 in your case] your vector must have a number of rows equal to `b` [= 2 in your case]. Given your 2 x 1 vector the final result will be a 3 x 1 vector

Now when you run the code `len(matrix)` gives back 3, as it should be. If you run the original version you had 2 as value back and that prevented the last calculation to get the remaining third element of the resulting vector [i.e. the final `14`]

```
def matVec(matrix,vector):
  result = []
  for i in range(len(matrix)):
    total = 0    
    for j in range(len(vector)):
      total += matrix[i][j] * vector[j]
    result.append(total)
  return result

matrix_0 = [[1, 2],[2, 3],[3, 4]]
vector_0 = [2, 2]
print(matVec(matrix_0,vector_0))
```

Comment: such as 2[6,10,14]

Comment: No worries, my pleasure. I edited my answer adding more details to give you a better explanation of what I did to fix. Fixing is only the last part while understanding the reason creating the problem will help you grow as coder... have a good weekend!